# Save media query in variable

Tags: variables, media-queries, sass

Is it possible to save a media query as a variable?

This don't work:

```
$max: @media (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 768px);
```

I'm not looking for how to save max-width and min-width, but the whole string.

Comment: Daniels answer works and should be selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use something like this

```
  @mixin respondTo($media) {
    @if $media == smallScreen {
      @media only screen and (max-width: $screenSmall - 1) { @content; }
    } @else if $media == mediumScreen {
      @media only screen and (max-width: $screenMedium) and (min-width: $screenSmall) { @content; }
    } @else if $media == largeScreen {
      @media only screen and (min-width: $screenXlarge) { @content; }
    }
  }
```

Then you can do something like the following:

```
.products {
  @include respondTo(smallScreen) {
    width: 300px;
  }

  @include respondTo(mediumScreen) {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Sass 3.2, you can store the media query in a variable like this:

```
$bp-small: "(min-width: 30em)";

@media #{$bp-small} {
    .foo {
        color: red;
    }
}
```